# No me funciona el filtro por selects en datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, postgresql, datatables

Estoy utilizando el plugin "datatables" de forma server-side, sirve perfectamente pero si le agrego los "select inputs" no me funciona, solo, esa opción. 
Obtuve el código del siguiente enlace: [enlace de la API](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)

Acá el código Ajax:

```html
var table = $('#table').DataTable({
    "destroy": true,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "ajax": "tabla/usuarios",
    "columns": [
        {data: 0, searchable: false, orderable: false, render: function( data, type, full, meta ){
                return meta.row+1;
            }
        },
        {data: 1},
        {data: 2},
        {data: 10},
        {data: 12},
        {data: 5, searchable: false, render: function( data, type, full, meta ){
                if (data) {
                    return '<input id="toggle" data-info="toggle'+full.id+'" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Activo" data-off="Inactivo" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">';
                }else {
                    return '<input id="toggle" data-info="toggle'+full.id+'" name="my-checkbox" type="checkbox"         data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Activo" data-off="Inactivo" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">';
                }
            }
        },
        {data: 9, searchable: false, orderable: false},
        /*
            data:
            0 - id
            1 - name
            2 - email
            3 - cedula
            4 - nombre
            5 - status
            6 - nombres
            7 - apellidos
            8 - id_perfiles
            9 - botones de editar y eliminar
            10 - boton info de cedula
            11 - password
            12 - boton info perfil
        */
    ],
    order: [[1, 'asc']],
    fnDrawCallback: function() {
        $("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapToggle();
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                placement : 'top',
                html : true
        }); 
    },
    "language": {
        "url": "js/idioma_espaniol_datatables.js"
    },
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    }
});
```

```
Route::get('tabla/usuarios', 'UsuariosController@tabla');
```

Acá el código del Controlador:

```html
public function tabla(){
    try{
        $sqls = User::join('personas','users.id_personas','=','personas.id')
                    ->join('perfiles','users.id_perfiles','=','perfiles.id')
                    ->select(array(
                        'users.id', 
                        'users.name', 
                        'users.email',
                        'personas.cedula', 
                        'perfiles.nombre', 
                        'users.status', 
                        'users.password', 
                        'personas.nombres', 
                        'personas.apellidos', 
                        'users.id_perfiles', 
                    ));
        return Datatables::of($sqls)
        ->addColumn('botones', '<button type="button" class="editar edit-modal btn btn-warning "><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Editar</button> <button type="button" class="eliminar delete-modal btn btn-danger"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Eliminar</button>')
        ->addColumn('cedula-popover', function ($sql) {
            return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Datos Personales" data-content="Nombres: '.$sql->nombres.' <br /> Apellidos: '.$sql->apellidos.'">'.$sql->cedula.'</button>';
        })
        ->addColumn('password', function ($sql) {
            return bcrypt($sql->password);
        })
        ->addColumn('funciones', function ($sql) {
            $result = \SIMante\Funciones::join('perfiles_funciones','perfiles_funciones.id_funciones','=','funciones.id')
                        ->select(array('funciones.nombre'))
                        ->where('perfiles_funciones.id_perfiles', '=', $sql->id_perfiles)->get();
            $funciones = "";
            for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++){
                $funciones = $funciones . " - " . $result[$i]->nombre . " <br /> ";
            }
            return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Funciones" data-content="'.$funciones.' <br />">'.$sql->nombre.'</button>';
        })
        ->make();
    }catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
        $array = array(
            'mensaje' => $e->getMessage(),
            'codigo' => $e->getCode(),
            'sql' => $e->getSql(),
            'bindings' => $e->getBindings(),
        );
        return Response::json(array('ErrorSql' => $array));
    }
}
```

Cuando selecciono una de las opciones de los "selects" me envia esto:

```html
{
  "ErrorSql": {
    "mensaje": "SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «REGEXP»\nLINE 1: ...rfiles\" = \"perfiles\".\"id\" where LOWER(users.name) REGEXP $1)...\n ^ (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as \"row_count\" from \"users\" inner join \"personas\" on \"users\".\"id_personas\" = \"personas\".\"id\" inner join \"perfiles\" on \"users\".\"id_perfiles\" = \"perfiles\".\"id\" where LOWER(users.name) REGEXP ^admin$) count_row_table)",
    "codigo": "42601",
    "sql": "select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as \"row_count\" from \"users\" inner join \"personas\" on \"users\".\"id_personas\" = \"personas\".\"id\" inner join \"perfiles\" on \"users\".\"id_perfiles\" = \"perfiles\".\"id\" where LOWER(users.name) REGEXP ?) count_row_table",
    "bindings": [
      "^admin$"
    ]
  }
}
```

Me dice que es un error de sintaxis, pero, ¿por que?.

La tabla me funciona bien, acá la demostración:
[image: Acá todo bien]
Pero si selecciono uno de los selects me lanza lo siguiente:
[image: Acá el error]

Comment: Puedes agregar el codigo que se ejecuta cuando cambias el selector? Quizas ordenar un poco tu codigo por : tabla, ajax, filtro, etc

Comment: @sioesi el codigo del filtrado esta en el "initComplete"

Comment: @MarcosGallardo disculpa no me percate que la pag me suprimio ese código, pero en el código mio si esta. Revise bien y todos las etiquetas me las elimino. ¿Como las podria agregar?

Comment: [Edita tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/39082/edit) y agrega el codigo nuevamente.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo ya la edite

Comment: `Laravel Datatable` no soporta [búsqueda usando `RegExp`](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/regex) en `PostgreSQL`. En `PostgreSQL` la función para buscar usando `RegExp` se llama [`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP) y en [`QueryBuildeEngine.php`](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/blob/06c8e551cdb6ddd9242e7ba4a6dab011c902f15c/src/Engines/QueryBuilderEngine.php#L600) se puede ver que solo soporta 2 funciones `REGEXP_LIKE` (`Oracle`) y `REGEXP` para todos los demas.

Comment: Entonces la solución seria ¿cambiar mi motor de base de datos?

Comment: Esa sería la última opción. Creo que se pueden hacer varias cosas antes, por ejemplo, un `pull request` al repo de la librería con el `fix`, parchar temporalmente la librería (no muy aconsejable), usar `filterColunm` para hacerlo a mano (para cada una de las columnas), ver otro método que se pueda usar para inyectar filtro custom, etc.

Comment: Ok investigare acerca de eso, lo que veo extraño es ¿porque me funciona el filtrado por el input, pero por los selects No? deberia de ser mas facil por columna que por el input que trabaja todas las columnas a su vez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de investigar poco a poco solucione el problema, ademas lo hice independiente en un select y un checkbox con on Change.

Acá la solución:

Acá para un select:

```
this.api().data(4).each( function (i , j) {
    $('#perfil').append( ''+i[4]+'' )
}); 
var column4 = this.api().column(4);
$('#perfil').on( 'change', function () {
    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
        $(this).val()
    );
    column4.search(val).draw();
});
```

Acá para un checkbox:

```
var column5 = this.api().column(5);
$('#estados').on("change", function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
            'true'
        );
        column5.search(val).draw();
    }else{
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
            'false'
        );
        column5.search(val).draw();
    }
});
```

Comment: @MarcosGallardo elimine esto: "column.search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false ).draw();" y lo sustitui por esto: "column4.search(val).draw();". Gracias por la ayuda en los comentarios cuando lo pregunte.